# Environment variable assignment followed by command

Tags: bash

What exactly is happening in the below bash incantation?

```
x=10 echo $x
```

I was under the impression that commands on bash can be chained using `&&`, `||` or `;` but not simply separated by white-space. The above only works if the first command is an assignment. E.g. `ls ls` fails but `foo=zoo ls` works just fine.

A real case of the above style is found in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3531768/274677).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a special syntactic construction to invoke a command with a variable set.
It means that the scope of the variable is limited to that command.

For example, this command:

```
x=10 sh -c 'echo $x'
```

Is quite equivalent to this other command:

```
( export x=10; sh -c 'echo $x' )
```

The example you gave (`x=10 echo $x`) is not an appropiate example of this construction because the variable `$x` is evaluated before `echo` is invoked.

Comment: Thanks, but where is this mentioned in the bash manual?

Comment: I can't find it there. I learned it by seeing it in a lot of scripts.

Comment: Actually there is a link in cuonglm's answer...

Answer (score 4):

When you do:

```
var=value command
```

you had passed string `var=value` to the environment of command. This environment will be used when command is executed.

From [bash - Environment](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Environment) documentation:

> **The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented
>   temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments**, as described
>   in Shell Parameters. These assignment statements affect only the
>   environment seen by that command.

But in your case, the command doesn't work. Because:

- In most shells, `echo` is a builtin function, therefore will not executed.
- `$x` had been expanded by the shell.

Comment: Upvoted! For official doc link and explaining OP's example's subtleties.

Comment: Though I'm not sure if "therefore will not executed" makes sense.

Comment: @flow2k agree, I don't see any other similar answers say "not executed", but all say it is "expand before execute". See [Why can't I specify an environment variable and echo it in the same command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938483/why-cant-i-specify-an-environment-variable-and-echo-it-in-the-same-command-line) and [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/628236/208590)

Answer (score 3):

Your command assets variable x to your value for the specific command you are running, instead of setting it in your shell. Local assignment so to say.

You can use this to either set or change an existing variable for one command.

Other uses I've used is

```
http_proxy=myproxy wget http://myurl
```

This will set a specific proxy for that particular url, without changing your shells default proxy setting.

```
LANG=C sort file
```

Sort your file based on a specific language setting, but only for that particular execution.