# Command-line variable assignment and command execution

Tags: bash, command-line, less

While researching more in-depth information about Bash subshells, I ran into an interesting execution that I would like to understand why it works. The execution involves assigning a string to a variable that is then used when `man` is called, [link to original example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264678/394038). I have already read about why the specific variable `LESS` is used in that example (`man` has `less` as its default pager in many distros), what I do not understand is how a variable assignment followed by a command execution works without any kind of separating metacharacters.

`LESS=+/'OPTIONS' man man` opens the man page for the `man` command directly under the `OPTIONS` section. It works with files opened directly with `less` too (which leads me to believe that the `LESS` variable is used by `less` the same way as doing a regex search within a `less` "session"). The `LESS` variable is not being exported, it's never saved in the current shell environment (executing `echo $LESS` returns nothing) so how is `less` capturing that value?

Why does that work, but not something like `foo='hello' echo $foo`? This case only works when a command separator (`;`) is included between the variable assignment and the command execution. I even tried `foo=+'hello' echo $foo` in case `=+` did something I was not aware in Bash, but no changes in the output.

Any explanations or reading material are welcome!

Comment: Related: [How do I set an environment variable on the command line and have it appear in commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56444/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-command-line-and-have-it-appear-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a standard feature. You can set the variable when launching the command and then the variable will be set for the command. It also works in the example you show, `foo='hello' echo $foo`. The problem is that you are testing the wrong way. When you run this:

```
foo='hello' echo $foo
```

The shell will expand the variable *before* running the command. Since `foo` is not actually set when you launch it, that becomes `echo`  (echo nothing). You can see this with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ foo='hello' echo $foo
+ foo=hello
+ echo
```

Now, compare that to what happens if you instead use a little script so that the variable is not seen by your shell:

```
$ cat ~/scripts/foo.sh
+ cat /home/terdon/scripts/foo.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "The value of foo is:$foo"
```

Use that to echo the variable and you get:

```
$ foo='hello' ~/scripts/foo.sh
+ foo=hello
+ /home/terdon/scripts/foo.sh
The value of foo is:hello
```

You can do the same thing if you call `bash -c` and enclose the command you give it in single quotes so the variable will be protected and not expanded by your current shell before calling `bash -c`:

```
$ foo='hello' bash -c 'echo $foo'
hello
```

While this fails because the double quotes mean that `$foo` is being expanded before `bash -c` ever sees it:

```
$ foo='hello' bash -c "echo $foo"

$
```

---

The behavior is documented in `man bash` in the "ENVIRONMENT" section:

```
   The environment for any simple command or  function  may  be  augmented
   temporarily  by  prefixing  it with parameter assignments, as described
   above in PARAMETERS.  These assignment statements affect only the envi‐
   ronment seen by that command.
```

It's also described in detail in the manual: [3.7.1 Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion)

Comment: Therefore, the main reason why ````LESS=+/'OPTIONS' man man```` works "as intended" but ````foo='hello' echo $foo```` doesn't is because Bash expansions always occur first so when foo is expanded it hasn't been set yet (kind of like a race condition?).

Comment: @AnthonyBB pretty much, yes. The variables are expanded before launching the command so the command never sees the variable, it only ever sees its value. If you think about it, that is the only way variables _could_ work. The whole idea is that if you have `x=12`, then `x` will always be treated as 12. Otherwise, what's the point of having variables in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! Understanding the ****why**** of things is one of my main goals and pleasures as a sysadmin.