# How to set one-command-lifelong variables in the shell?

Tags: shell, terminal, environment-variables

Consider the following example:

```bash
file="test" echo $file
```

My idea is that `file` persists only during the command `echo $file`. Although `$file` does not persist after this command, `echo` prints nothing, as if `$file` were not set.

Is it possible to set one-command-lifelong variables in the shell?

**edit**: I don't want to resort to shell scripts or functions as suggested in [all](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56444/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-command-line-and-have-it-appear-in-c) [these](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628231/command-line-variable-assignment-and-command-execution) [related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628231/command-line-variable-assignment-and-command-execution) [questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56444/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-command-line-and-have-it-appear-in-c.)

Comment: Relating (duplicate?): https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/628231/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller It is related but not duplicated, at all. He/She looks for persistent variable assignment during command execution. I look for nonpersistent variable assignment during command execution.

Comment: The linked Q&A does explain what’s happening in your test: `file` *is* set only for `echo`, but `$file` is expanded before `echo` runs (it has to be) so `$file` is empty when it’s expanded. Try the example given in the linked answer, using a shell script: you’ll see that the variable is indeed set for the command (in a non-persistent manner).

Comment: ... see also [How do I set an environment variable on the command line and have it appear in commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56444/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-command-line-and-have-it-appear-in-c)

Comment: "*The linked Q&A does explain what’s happening in your test*". I am not asking "What happens with `file`?".  "*Try the example given in the linked answer, using a shell script*", my idea is to not resort to shell scripts. I have a answer for my own question (none of the aforementioned Q&A answered it). Open it so that I can answer it.

Comment: The thing is, your command here, `file="test" echo $file` does exactly what you want it to do. Can you edit and clarify the use case? Do you _really_ want the variable to only be available in the command's environment, or do you want it to be available in the parent (which is what `echo "$var"` requires) but to then be unset after the command finishes?  If you only want it to exist in the command's environment, "for the lifetime of the command" then `var=foo command` is the right way.

Comment: Just to throw a more gasoline on the fire, part of the problem with your test case, is that `echo` doesn't care about any variables in the environment, (except when they are embedded in the cmd line arguments or as otherwise evaluated by the cmd-processing loop). But take the case of a program that has its own env var, `less`, If you have an env var `export LESS=-CQaix4`, you can override  that (just the one time) with `LESS= less /path/to/some/file`. When you open the file all of the features from `-CQaix4` are gone. `less` is always looking in its environment for `$LESS`. (just for example).

Comment: OP's preferred version is given In https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56454/70524: "Portably (Bourne and POSIX): `(var=value; echo "1: $var"); echo "2: $var"` The (...) above starts a sub-shell".

Comment: See also [In bash, how I define a "command scope" variable?](https://superuser.com/q/801822/354511)

Answer (score 1):

The command

```bash
file="test" echo $file
```

doesn't output `test` because **the expansion occurs before running the command**. Check this out:

```bash
$ set -x
$ foo='hello' echo $foo
+ foo=hello
+ echo
```

The same thing doesn't occur when you run a Unix shell script instead of running a shell command, e.g.,

```bash
foo='hello' /path/to/script.sh
```

In this case, the `foo='hello'` assignment is first resolved, then `/path/to/script.sh` is run.

Some [previous](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628231/command-line-variable-assignment-and-command-execution) and [related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628231/command-line-variable-assignment-and-command-execution) [posts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56444/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-command-line-and-have-it-appear-in-c) proposed solutions for persistent variable assignment + CLI commands:

1. `foo='hello' bash -c 'echo $foo'`: Using shell script is not desirable! Wordy approach to simple commands.
2. `(){ local var=value; echo "1: $var"; }; echo "2: $var"`: Using functions is not desirable! Wordy approach to simple commands.
3. `TEST=foo && echo $TEST`: Simple but persistent.

My way out is

```bash
(file="test"; echo $file)
```

By creating a subshell, you can create a shell variable, use it in the `echo` command, and then it won't persist outside this command.

Comment: Can you explain why you consider examples 1 and 2 as creating “persistent” variables? If `foo` is initially unset, after `foo=hello bash -c 'echo $foo'` it remains unset.

Comment: @StephenKitt I edited to make clearer which solutions make persistent environment variables.

Comment: I don't understand this. `var=value command` is exactly what you want: it sets the variable `var` to `value` _only_ for the execution environment of `command`. Your solution here actually does make it persist outside, it's just that you are adding the extra step of running a subshell and the variable is set only in the subshell. So once the subshell exits, you no longer have the variable set, but that isn't what your question asked for.

Comment: `file='test' eval 'echo $test'` has the advantage that it does not create an extra shell.

Comment: `(){ local var=value; echo "1: $var"; }` same as `function { local var=value; echo "1: $var"; }` is zsh syntax for an *anonymous function*. See also `var=value command eval 'echo "$var"'` which works in many shells.

Comment: re. _"The same thing doesn't occur when you run a Unix shell script instead running a shell command, e.g.,"_, well, that's not true, e.g. try `foo='hello' /path/to/script.sh "$foo"` with some script that uses `"$1"`. Same with `foo=bar sh -c 'echo ">$1<"' sh "$foo"`.

Comment: It's also a bit unclear why you say "Using shell script is not desirable! " and "Using functions is not desirable!" (esp. with exclamation marks) as the first comment about those. Is it that you just want axiomatically avoid scripts or functions, or is it that you see some downsides in those solutions? If the latter, which downsides?

Comment: @terdon, well, in e.g. `(foo=xyz; echo "$foo"); echo "$foo"` the modified value of `foo` effectively persists only for the duration of the first `echo` (including the expansions in that command), not the rest of the script (the second `echo`), so IMO, it looks to fill their desire exactly. Too bad something like `foo=xyz { whatever... }` doesn't work.

Comment: re. `TEST=foo && echo $TEST`, this is same as just `TEST=foo; echo $TEST`, and would be clearer written that way. That is, unless you have a command substitution  on the right-hand side of the assignment (`TEST=$(foo) && echo $TEST`), in which the `&&` would test the result of that, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The variable binding in your command line doesn't take place until the command line is executed. But the parameter substitution of `$file` takes place while the command is expanded, which must happen before it is executed.

The way around this is to put your command into a function:

```
fun()
{
   echo "file = " $file
}

file=abc fun
```

Comment: Note that when prefixing *functions* with `var=value`, [POSIX leaves it unspecified](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) *whether or not the variable assignments persist after the completion of the function*. In practice, it doesn't in ksh.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Works as an override in Bash and Zsh also; work as a dumb assignment in Dash.